# HTTP GET Request with Provider doesnt work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

so I have a GET request that needs authorization headers, and I've tried using Postman manually where it works just fine, but not in my Dart code.

So I have this announcements.dart Provider class:

```dart
class Announcements with ChangeNotifier {
  List _items = [];
  String? token;

  // late Future<Announcement> futureAnnouncement;

  Announcements(this.token, this._items);

  List get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Future<void> fetchAnnouncements() async {
    String url = "https://api-staging.xxx.us.org/1.0/announcements";
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: token!},
      );
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
      final List loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, data) {
        loadedProducts.add(
            Announcement(id: prodId, title: data['title'], body: data['body']));
      });
      print(response);
      _items = loadedProducts;
      print(_items);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      throw (e);
    }
```

and this is my main.dart function where the ChangeNotifier works:

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Announcements>(
          create: (_) => Announcements(null, []),
          update: (_, auth, previousProducts) => Announcements(
            auth.token,
            previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'Xxx',
          theme: ThemeData(),
          home: NavigationScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how the announcement is called:

```dart
class AnnouncementScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final announcementData = Provider.of<Announcements>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff1e1e1e),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 90,
              ),
              Text(
                'Good Morning, John',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32,
                  fontFamily: 'Casper',
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 245, 232, 1),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: Provider.of<Announcements>(context)
                        .fetchAnnouncements(),
                    builder: (ctx, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting
                        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                        : ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: announcementData.items.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Column(
                                children: [
                                  _tile(announcementData.items[index].title,
                                      announcementData.items[index].body),
                                  Divider(
                                    thickness: 4,
                                    indent: 0,
                                    endIndent:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(198, 158, 96, 1),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping, really appreciate it!

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: Take the request part out of your code and run it. Let me know what do you get in `response` and `response.body` as well. Also,  what `status code` are you getting?

Comment: @JohnJoe hi, I didn't get any error. i think there are some provider error there

Comment: @DetainedDeveloper hi, I didn't get any error. i think there are some provider error there

Comment: @EdwardTanoto not errors, just what `response` are you getting from the server, along with `status code`, like 401, 403. So we can find out what's going wrong.

Comment: @DetainedDeveloper hi, the print(response) doesnt give any response in the provider code, however print(url) works fine for some reason

Comment: @DetainedDeveloper Hi, I got flutter: {"status":400,"error":"Missing or invalid Authorization header. Authorization: bearer [token]"}

Answer (score 0):

There are certain things you need to change, I don't know exactly what's the problem in this code.
I think the fetching is happening but the widget rebuilds so many times, which makes the future be fetched every time the rebuild happens, which again trigger the rebuild

1. Change the Widget to StatefulWidget
2. Extract the fields inside didChangeDependencies (since you need context)

```flutter
class AnnouncementScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnnouncementScreenState createState() => _AnnouncementScreenState();
}

class _AnnouncementScreenState extends State<AnnouncementScreen > {
  late final announcementFuture;
  late final Announcements announcement;
  bool isInitialised = false;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
   super.didChangeDependencies();
   if(!isInitialised ){
     announcement = Provider.of<Announcements>(context);
     announcementFuture =  announcement.fetchAnnouncements();
     isInitialised = true;
     }
 }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ....(
        FutureBuilder(
                    future:announcementFuture ,
                     builder: (ctx,snapshot){
                        //code
                       }
                    ),
       ...
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, it still doesnt work for some reason. i think the mistake might be in providers? (no error too)

Comment: the error is because flutter: {"status":400,"error":"Missing or invalid Authorization header. Authorization: bearer [token]"}

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the auth token is loaded in your project?
It may be easier to debug this if you create a simple Dart command line app that makes the calls you need. Then you can do something like:

```
void main() async {
  try {
    final auth = Auth();
    final token = auth.whateverMethodGetsToken();
    // Note: Announcements class shouldn't really need ChangeNotifier 
    final announcements = Announcements(token, []);
    final result = announcements.fetchAnnouncements();
    print(result);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

This will tell you if the problem is in your networking code and make it easier to debug it.